# Prove that if $na_n \rightarrow L \neq 0$, then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I know it is possible to prove it with the limit comparison test: if we let $b_n = \frac{1}{n}$, then $\frac{a_n}{b_n} = \frac{a_n}{\frac{1}{n}} = na_n \rightarrow L$. This implies that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ has the same behavior of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}$, which diverges. But for that we have to assume that $a_n \geq 0 \; \forall n$.

Is it possible to prove it without that assumption? If not, what is a counterexample?

Edit: I thought of assuming WLOG that $L > 0$. Then $\exists N $ such that $n > N \implies a_n > 0$, and the limit comparison test could be used. Is that reasoning correct? The argument for $L <0$ would just use $b_n = - \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: You can assume $L>0$. For $n$ suitable large, $a_n \ge {L \over 2} {1 \over n}$. Now use comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence $a_n$ eventually has the same sign as $L$. So if $L > 0$, the condition you need is already satisfied. If $L<0$, then the sequence $n(-a_n)$ has a positive limit, so by the same argument, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-a_n)$ diverges.

Answer (score 1):

To understand the behaviour of the series $\sum a_n$ you just need to look at the behaviour of the sequence $a_n$ for $n$ big enough. Your assumption tells you that for all $n > N$ (for some $N > 0$) then $a_n$ has the same sign as that of $L$. So you can restrict your series to $\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} a_n$ and apply your technique.